# React Native Syntax

Tags: react-native

Excuse the noobie question, but when I am going through the react native docs there are syntax differences to regular javascript. I am trying to figure out where the docs are that describe the syntax.

For example this statement

```
var {
  ActivityIndicatorIOS,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
} = React
```

And the use of the => operator in

```
  setToggleTimeout: function() {
    this.setTimeout(
      () => {
        this.setState({animating:     !this.state.animating});
        this.setToggleTimeout();
      },
      1200
    );
  },
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are ECMAScript 6 features

Your first example is a destructuring assignment

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

And the second one is an arrow function

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 4):

Accepted answer above is correct, but here are some examples:

First: an example of ES6 Destructuring:

```
var {
  ActivityIndicatorIOS,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
} = React
```

is exactly analogous to:

```
var ActivityIndicatorIOS = React.ActivityIndicatorIOS;
var StyleSheet = React.StyleSheet;
var View = React.View;
```

This is a nice shorthand approach. Of course, destructuring is more powerful than that and the Mozilla docs give further examples.

2nd: An example of an ES6 arrow function (or fat arrow function)

```
setToggleTimeout: function() {
    this.setTimeout(
      () => {
        this.setState({animating:     !this.state.animating});
        this.setToggleTimeout();
      },
      1200
    );
  },
```

Advantages are a less code to write, but a critical difference is that in arrow functions the 'this' is the same 'this' as the context it is written in. In other words, you don't have to use bind() anymore.

The bad old days:

```
setToggleTimeout: function() {
        this.setTimeout(
          function() {
            this.setState({animating:     !this.state.animating});
            this.setToggleTimeout();
          }.bind(this),
          1200
        );
      },
```

Comment: Very interesting this answer for mentioning the binding of this. It took me a while to discover that.